# Как правильно вычислить разницу между двумя заданными датами php

Tags: php, mysql

Как вычислить количество дней между двумя датами?

В таблице MySQL есть поля `arrival` и `departure`. Записаны в `varchar` в такой форме `03/14/2019`. Передаю данные через input data.

Пробовал так, но не получается:

```
 $date1 = $post['departure']; 
 $date2 = $post['arrival']; 
 $diff = $date1 - $date2; 
 echo $diff;
```

Comment: пробывал так не получается $date1 = $post['departure'];
$date2 = $post['arrival'];
$diff = $date1 - $date2;

echo $diff;

Answer (score 1):

> записаны в varchar в такой форме 03/14/2019.

Это неправильно. Дата должна быть записана в БД в формате 2019-03-13.
Поэтому перед записью в базу ее надо переформатировать.

после этого разницу можно будет получить прямо в запросе:

```
SELECT to_days(departure) - to_days(arrival) as duration, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример взят [отсюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php):

```
# Первое значение 
# Так же можно вставить вашу дату из <input>
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');

# Второе значение 
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%R%a дней');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 abs ( floor( (strtotime(date2) - strtotime(date1)) / 24*3600 ) )
```

Comment: у вас неточность - нужно секунды в сутках в скобки взять.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего это сделать не средствами php, а средствами самого MySQl в запросе. Например что-то вроде:

select DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(arrival,'%d/%m/%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(departure,'%d/%m/%Y')) as duration from tablename;

Comment: Этот запрос вернет полную ерунду